# Items icons with listview and imagelist

Tags: vb.net, listview, imagelist

Hello I've got a list view that opens items inside a folder and displays them. I want to know if there is a way to have the list view display the icons aswell, maybe using shell32 or an imagelist. Here's the code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class cv7import

Private Sub cv7import_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim caminho As String
    caminho = "C:\Documents and Settings\Software\Ambiente de trabalho\1"



    lstvicon.View = View.Details
    lstvicon.GridLines = False
    lstvicon.FullRowSelect = True
    lstvicon.HideSelection = False
    lstvicon.MultiSelect = True


    lstvicon.Columns.Add("Nome")
    lstvicon.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)

    Dim DI As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(caminho)

    Dim files() As System.IO.FileInfo = DI.GetFiles

    Dim file As System.IO.FileInfo

    Dim li As ListViewItem
    For Each file In files
        li = lstvicon.Items.Add(file.Name)
        li.Tag = file.FullName
    Next
End Sub


End Class
```

Here's two images, of how it looks and how I want it to look, if it helps.

How I wanted: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/wantd.png/

How it looks: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/13/needk.png/

Comment: Which icon do you want to show? The one associated with the file like file explorer does?

Comment: Yes, if it's a .txt I want it to show the .txt icon.

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to find the extension of the file to start with:

```
Dim file As String = "C:\scratch\newfile.txt"
Dim ext as string = IO.Path.GetExtension(file)
```

Then you need to find this entry in the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` section of the registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt
```

The default value in this key gives the file type associated with this file in my case `txtfile` (remember that different registries may have different values depending on what the user has set up and what programs are installed)

You then need to look up this values `DefaultIcon` key in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\DefaultIcon
```

The default value in here gives you the location of the icon and the icon number in my case:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-102
```

From this point I think you may need to rely on the [ExtractIconEX API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
to extract the icon. [This link](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.extracticonex) may also be of use

Comment: Thanks but I dont think I can you that, since this program is going to be used on several PCs, so if I try to define it to use the icon from one file in a folder, and the file does not exist it will bug out.

Comment: Yes, the problem is, that the icons are embedded in DLLs and EXEs. They are not available as icon file.

Comment: Yes you can extract the icon from the embedded DLL or EXE using ExtractIconEx, you can do this on the fly as you find each file. These values can/will be different on each machine which is why you will need to read the registry each time to find which icon to extract

Answer (score 0):

`ListViewItems` have `ImageList`, `ImageIndex` and `ImageKey` properties. Add a `ImageList` control to your form (from the components group in the toolbox). You can add images to the `ImageList` by clicking "Choose images" below the property grid, when the image list is selected. Then assign the image list and an image index or an image key to your list items.

Comment: I've tried doing that but I keep getting bugs when it comes to identify the extension.

Comment: You mean, that you do not know how to find an icon corresponding to a specific file extension and that your problem is not displaying an icon, but finding an icon?

Comment: It's both. I know that most default icons are on shell32.dll but I have no idea on how to import them to my listview on VB nor how to display them acording to extension. I've tried several options but I've had no luck so any help is apreciated.

Comment: Matt shows you the way to go if you want a programmatical approach. It is not an easy one. May it would be sufficient to hold a set of only the most common icons in an ImageList. There are a lot of free icon editors and icon extractors that will do the job of extracting the icons.